# Window topmost confusion - and no way out?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a fullscreen  *MainWindow*. From The *MainWindow* the user can open a *PreviewWindow*. The *PreviewWindow* is a modal window so it is on top of the MainWindow. So far so good.

Still the user is able to select the *MainWindow* from the Windows Taskbar while the *PreviewWindow* is open. Then the *PreviewWindow* is hidden under the *MainWindow* but the *MainWindow* is inavtive since the *PreviewWindow* is still the only active window. For the user it looks like the application is not responding anymore.

I don't know why my users work like that but they do and it causes a lot of confusion.

Our first solution was the make the *PreviewWindow* topmost but that did not help much. From the *PreviewWindow* the user can open a *SaveDialog*. But with the *PreviewWindow* topmost the *SaveDialog* is hidden under the *PreviewWindow*.

My idea is to make the *PreviewWindow* topmost untill the user opens the *SaveDialog*. And make it topmost again after the *SaveDialog* has endet.

Is this the only way to do it?
Is there a way to bring a modal window back to top when its parent window is choosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are not complete or relevant. Sorry guys ;)

Use ShowDialog() in order to wait end of second window before continuing with first window. Use Owner property to link windows.

```
   previewWindow = new Window2();
   previewWindow.Owner = this;
   previewWindow.ShowDialog();
```

That's work with 3 or more windows if you want (w1 launch w2, w2 launch w3, ...). When selecting first window in taskbar, all windows will appear.

You don't need to set TopMost or ShowInTaskbar properties (but you can if you want particular behaviour)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Make sure your PreviewWindow has `ShowInTaskbar` set to `False`.
2. Set `PreviewWindow.Owner = MainWindow` and then try with both `Show()` and `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All I had to do was set the owner!

Comment: @Xaruth: I have been bitten by Point no. 1 a few times. You don't want to see a child window/dialog appear in the taskbar. Anyway, glad to see you were able to solve ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a modal window, you should be displaying it using [Window.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).

Is there some reason you cannot do that?

Comment: It works, until you hide all windows and then show first windows on clicking on taskbar (the second doesn't appear and first can't be focused). That's the point of the question.

Comment: And you set PreviewWindow.Owner to MainWindow?

Comment: that's complete the answer ;)